# Matrix --> Scalar Valued Function: Differentiation

Tags: matrices, derivatives, intuition, linear-transformations

In class, we called a real-valued function from the space of matrices to the reals $f: \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ differentiable at $\mathbf{X}$ if:

$$\lim_{\mathbf{H} \to \mathbf{0_{m \times n}}} \frac{\lvert\lvert f(\mathbf{X} + \mathbf{H}) - f(\mathbf{X}) - tr([\nabla f(\mathbf{X})^T]\mathbf{H})\rvert \rvert}{\lvert\lvert \mathbf{H}\rvert\rvert} = 0$$

where the gradient is the transpose of the total derivative. In this definition of differentiability, I'm trying to understand the intuition behind using the $tr(\cdot)$.

1. In this case, is it true that the total derivative $\mathscr{D}f$ is a map $\mathscr{D}f : \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \rightarrow \mathscr{L}(\mathbb{R}^{m \times n},\mathbb{R})$?
2. If the above is true, then $tr([\mathscr{D}f](\mathbf{H})) = [\mathscr{D}f](\mathbf{H})$ since $[\mathscr{D}f](\mathbf{H})$ is a real number. So do we take the trace just for convenience in manipulating the algebraic expressions of the matrices? Could we use $det(\cdot)$ instead?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the definition of the derivative transformation itself? It is unclear to me from the definition. Also when you say matrix-valued, do you mean "real-valued on the space of matrices"? Because that's what it looks like you wrote.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I mean "real-valued on the space of matrices" and have edited.  For the definition of the derivative transformation, I think it's just a map from the space of matrices to the space of linear transformations from the space of matrices to the reals.

Comment: Right, but where does it appear in the difference quotient? How can one answer questions about $\mathscr{D}\!f$ without knowing what it is?

Comment: what is the textbook you are using for this course? I would like to learn more about this topic.

Comment: It's an optimization course, and we're using a number of different texts as references, but are largely going on class notes.  I've found Boyd's Convex Optimization useful. I can send some other PDFs that I've found (not tied to the course) if you'd like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: The function $\mathbf{X},\mathbf{Y}\to \operatorname{trace}(\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{Y})$ defines an inner product on the space $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$.

Long answer:
In the general setting of a finite-dimensional spaces $E$, the usual definition of Frechet derivative of function $f: E\to \mathbb R$ at point $x$ is the linear map $L\in \mathcal L(E,\mathbb R)$ such that $$\lim_{{h} \to 0} \frac{\lvert\lvert f(x+h) - f(x) - L(h)\rvert \rvert}{\lvert\lvert h\rvert\rvert} = 0$$

If you equip $E$ with an inner product $\langle .,. \rangle$, Riesz representation theorem tells you that there is a unique vector $u\in E$ such that $\forall y \in E, L(y)=\langle y,u \rangle$. The vector $u$ is usually called "gradient of $f$ at $x$", that's what you note $\nabla f(\mathbf{X})$. Now, note that the function $\mathbf{X},\mathbf{Y}\to \operatorname{trace}(\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{Y})$ defines an inner product on the space $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and you're done.

Comment: This is a great answer - so here the derivative is defined to be the linear functional corresponding to the inner product with the gradient of f?

Comment: @William Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thank you -- this clarifies why we use trace over determinant for me. My follow up question is: if we think about laying the gradient $\nabla f(\mathbf{X}) \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ side by side into a vector of dimension $1 \times mn$ (and stacking $\mathbf{H}$ into a $mn \times 1$ vector), then the $tr(\cdot)$ over matrices seems to correspond to the canonical inner product of covector / vector multiplication -- is this the right interpretation for using $tr(\cdot)$? Is there a way to view $\nabla f(\mathbf{X})^T$ as a higher order tensor taking $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ to $\mathbb{R}$?